# How to make update faster with Hibernate while using huge number of records

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, hibernate, indexing, hql

I am facing issue while using the hibernate update (Session.update()) portion with huge number of records. it is becoming very slower. but there is no issue with the insert (Session.insert()) portion. is there any way to do the update portion while we do update on lakh's of records.is there any way to tune the sql server so that the update will become faster. while we add seperate indexes to all the primary fields then the delete portion is taking time. is there any better way to tune sql server so that it performs well with insert, delete and update.

Thank you,
Saif.

Comment: can you post some of your code

Answer (score 2):

do a batch update instead of individual update for each record. this way you will only hit the database once for all the records.

Answer (score 1):

When you do a save only the data is saved into the database whereas when your updating a record it has to first perform the search operation and then update the record that is why your facing issues on update and not on save  when your are handling huge number of records can use hibernate's **BATCH PROCESSING** to update your records. Here is a good link for batch processing in hibernate from tutorials point:

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/hibernate/hibernate_batch_processing.htm

Answer (score 0):

There may be other solutions to this but one way I know is:

Whenever you save or update an instance through `session (e.g. session.save(), session.update(), session.saveOrUpdate() etc.)`, it also updates the instance FK associations.

So if your POJO has multiple FK associations, it will fire queries on those tables as well.

So instead of updating instance in this way, I would suggest to use HQL (if it applies to your requirement) to save or update instance.